# SAPUI5 Offline - How do I filter the definingRequest

Tags: sapui5, offline

I'd like to make use of SAP Cloud Platform's built in offline functionality.

Unfortunately the data will be far too large to implement offline, so I need to apply a filter to my defining requests.

```
"sap.mobile": {
"_version": "1.1.0",
"definingRequests": {},
"stores": [
    {
        "name": "ZSV_SURVEY_SRV",
        "serviceRoot": "/SAPUI5-ABAP-SFI/",
        "definingRequests": {
            "SurveySet": "/Surveyset"
        }
    }
]
```

}
I know I can setup a filter as follows:

```
SurveySet$Filter=userID.
```

How is userID passed in though?

E.g it would ideally filter on the logged in user's records

Answer (score 0):

Solution.... (component.js)

```
        var _sapClient = "test";
        var oManifestUi5 = this.getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.mobile");
        oManifestUi5.stores[0].definingRequests.SurveySet = "/SurveySet?filter=" + _sapClient;
```